# Switching low voltage with high accuracy

Tags: switches, low-voltage, solid-state-devices

To do some discharge tests, I want to connect 1.5 V batteries to very low resistances for a short amount (10 - 200 ms) of time, then have them disconnected for at least a couple of seconds.

What would be the best switching element and driver circuit to use for this?  I can think of either SSR, FET, or BJT, with SSR being the simplest, but not necessarily the best.

The control signal for the switching circuit will be 3.3 V logic level (can be either active high or active low), and I can use 3.3, 5, 9 or 12 V elsewhere in the driver circuit if needed.

The battery shall be no bigger than a D size rechargeable, and so I'd say the max. attempted current would be no more than 10 A (even if some could source more than that for a very short time).

I definitely want the switch's resistance below 1 Ω, though less would be preferable. I want to stay realistic with respect to available components and costs.

Here is a high-level schematic of what I'm trying to accomplish (I'm mostly a programmer, not an EE):

[image: High level schematic]

Comment: What switch resistance can you afford? (0Ω would require a superconductor.)

Comment: You may find that a logic level JFET, as discussed hete https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/601905/picking-a-fet-for-logic-level or here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/652322/is-p90nf03l-3-3v-logic-level-mosfet may be suitable for your task.

Comment: @JSz this site is not a forum ... it is a question and answer site... information  belongs in the question at the top of this page ... please edit your question and delete the comments

Comment: I should use a variable pulse current controlled source. One can start from 0 to Imax current.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any modern low voltage MOSFET will have an ON resistance well under 1 ohm. Many are just a few milliohms. Specific device recommendations are off-topic here. You might want to provide a schematic of how you intend to control the switching element, as such design questions are appropriate.